# Polymer 2 event bubbling

Tags: polymer-2.x

According to [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events), function *x(e,d,t)* in file *index.html* would not be called, but in fact it is. Am I misunderstanding something?

*dom-element.html*

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<dom-module id="dom-element">
  <template>
    <button on-click="c">Click me!</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    class DomElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return "dom-element"; }
      c(){
        /* this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('x',{bubbles:true,composed:true,detail:"We do not need this to work!"})); */
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('x',{detail:"yes"}));
      }
    }
    customElements.define(DomElement.is, DomElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="dom-element.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <dom-module id="root-element">
      <template>
          <dom-element on-x="x"></dom-element>
      </template>
      <script>
        class RootElement extends Polymer.Element{
          static get is() {return 'root-element'}
            x(e,d,t){
                console.log(d);
              }
        }
        customElements.define(RootElement.is,RootElement);
      </script>
    </dom-module>
    <root-element></root-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what I understand the idea is that your even doesn't bubble up outside of `dom-element`, but there you are listening for the "x" event on it. So if you remove the declarative way to listen (via on-x), and try to add in `root-element` an imperative listener (via this.addEventListener), your event won't reach the callback. (or if the listener would have been another level up)

Comment: @mishu I just tested according your instruction and got the result as you predicted. *Annotated event listener* appears to always catch both bubbling and non-bubbling events. It is an exception of the rule "By default, custom events stop at shadow DOM boundaries" as written in documentation, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's an exception, I am guessing that you're just adding the event listener on the element itself, so you're exactly "on" those shadow DOM boundaries.. personally I don't see much point in dispatching custom events inside an element without having them available on the element itself.. but I guess that if you find a case you would have to stop its propagation yourself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event `'x'` fired by `<dom-element>` in `<root-element>` doesn't cross shadow dom boundaries. `<root-element>` listens to an element in its own shadow dom, `<dom-element>`, which is the sender of the `'x'`, there is no boundary crossing involved.